# Use middle of a string variable in Chef

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I have a code like this in Chef

```
{
  'home/user1/folder/file.erb'=>'/home/user1/folder/file',
  'home/user2/folder/file.erb'=>'/home/user2/folder/file',
  'home/user3/folder/file.erb'=>'/home/user3/folder/file',
  'home/user4/folder/file.erb'=>'/home/user4/folder/file',

}.each do |s,d|
  template d do
    source s
    owner user
    group user
    mode '600'
  end
end
```

How do I replace value of owner and group with user1, user2, user3... from variable d?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Split Your Hash Values on `/`

There are certainly other ways to do this, but given your example an easy trick is simply to grab the user's directory from each hash value into a block-local variable at the top of each loop, which you can then reuse as needed. For example:

```
{
  'home/user1/folder/file.erb' => '/home/user1/folder/file',
  'home/user2/folder/file.erb' => '/home/user2/folder/file',
  'home/user3/folder/file.erb' => '/home/user3/folder/file',
  'home/user4/folder/file.erb' => '/home/user4/folder/file',
}.each do |src, dst|

  # capture username for use as owner & group
  usr = dst.split(?/)[2]

  template dest do
    source src
    owner  usr
    group  usr
    mode   '600'
  end
end
```

Using [String#split](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/String.html#method-i-split) works by breaking the string into an Array of elements using `/` as a separator. Indexing into the array with `[2]` gives you the third element, which is the username, which you are apparently also using for the group.

The fact that it's the third element rather than the second isn't intuitive. However, when you use #split on your sample code, you get results like this:

```
'/home/user4/folder/file'.split ?/
#=> ["", "home", "user4", "folder", "file"]
```

Because of the way #split works, your inputs will yield an empty string as the first element of each destination array. Since Ruby arrays are zero-indexed, the element you want is the third one (e.g. `[2]`) in each of your sample values.

There are certainly other ways to do this, but this is a simple way to do what you want without making significant changes to your code. It often helps to remember that Chef (and Puppet!) are really just DSLs built on top of Ruby, so you can often use standard Ruby methods to get the job done.